# I want to access EKS Redis cluster in Local Spring Boot Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, redis, kubernetes-helm

I set up Reids cluster with Helm in AWS EKS.

`kubectl get all -n redis`

```
NAME                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/redis-master-0     1/1     Running   0          22h
pod/redis-replicas-0   1/1     Running   0          22h
pod/redis-replicas-1   1/1     Running   0          22h
pod/redis-replicas-2   1/1     Running   0          22h

NAME                     TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
service/redis-headless   ClusterIP   None             <none>        6379/TCP   14d
service/redis-master     ClusterIP   172.20.135.211   <none>        6379/TCP   14d
service/redis-replicas   ClusterIP   172.20.161.174   <none>        6379/TCP   14d

NAME                              READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/redis-master     1/1     14d
statefulset.apps/redis-replicas   3/3     14d
```

and I want to Connect Redis to my local Spring Boot Project for test.
with application.properties

What is the Best Practice to connect it?
Thanks for detail guide to resolve it.

When I run Spring Boot project, connection with Redis will be completed